# inserting into an array of linked lists in java

Tags: arrays, dynamic, insert, linked-list, hashtable

I have an array of linked lists that I initialized by doing:

```
hashTable = (T[]) new Object[tableSize];

for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
    hashTable[i] = (T) new LinkedList<T>();
    // I want to add something to a linked list at element i of the array
    hashTable[i].insert(item);
}
```

What's the correct way of inserting into a linked list that is inside of an array?

Answer (score 0):

The method to "insert" into a List is called [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29).
And you need to give your array a type (of List) if you want to access this method.

```
List[] hashTable = new List[tableSize]; // terrible name for an array

for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
    hashTable[i] = new LinkedList<T>();
    // I want to add something to a linked list at element i of the array
    hashTable[i].add(item);
}
```